# Folland exercise 57 chapter 2 "Real Analysis"

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sxy}x^{-1}\sin(x)dx=\arctan(s^{-1})$ for $s>0$ by integrating $e^{-sxy}\sin(x)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$  (It may be useful to recall that $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)=(\tan\theta)^{-1}$). 
Someone can help me, please?

Comment: Presumably this should be a double integral? If so, try to use Fubini's theorem

Comment: I suspect there being a use of DCT or MCT here.

Comment: Exercise 57 in whose book?

Comment: @carmichael561 I tried Fubini's Theorem, but without success. And what would be the domain of integration?

Comment: @user587192 Gerald B. Folland, Real Analysis, modern techiniques and their applications.

Comment: The question doesn't quite make sense the way it's stated, so a good start would be to check the book and state the question correctly. Does Folland give any other hints?

Comment: @carmichael561 I copied it from the book.

Comment: Folland gives a hint that one may use Exercise 31(d): for $a>1$, $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}x^{-1}\sin x\ dx=\arctan(a^{-1}).$$ He also gives a hint that for doing this, which says that "derive the formula by expanding part of the integrand into an infinite sereis and justifying the term-by-term integration where Exercise 29 may be useful: $$ \int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\ dx=n!$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of how you can go about this which I think should be closer to how the answer was intended to be solved using the material in that section of the book. First, you can calculate $\int_0^\infty\int_1^\infty e^{-sxy}\sin(x)dydx=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-sx}\sin(x)}{x}dx.$ Next, you can calculate the double integral in the other order $\int_1^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-sxy}\sin(x)dxdy=\frac{1}{s}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(s)\right)$. Finally, you have to prove  that the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem applies to this function. Once that is done, you can say that these two double integrals are equal and so in particular $$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-sx}\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(s)=\arctan(1/s).$$